# Where to order small batches (say, 100 units) of custom boxes for your projects

Tags: pcb

I'm creating a simple effect for musical instruments and I'm wondering how I will package it when it'll be ready. I mean, I can create some kind of stomb box with my own hands but if I'm ever going to sell it I need to find a way to create some small batch of them. The problem is it's hard (impossible?) to find some manifacturer who cares of building, say, 100 boxes. On the other hand I cannot order thousends of them because I'm not sure I'll sell the out.

So has anyone faced/solved this problem in the past?
Thank you very much ;)

Comment: When I looked into it, the enclosure / stomp switch was the *hardest* part of making guitar effects.  The circuits inside are usually rather trivial.

Comment: Do you have a CNC mill?  It shouldn't take more than a day or two to modify/build 100 boxes, depending on how much customization you want.

Comment: @markrages Actually I'm making a midi-pedal for keyboards to do some interesting stuff. So, yeah, it's just something like a micro with a serial port and an LCD. :D


@reemrevnivek Unfortunately, I don't have a CNC mill :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use a service like [Ponoko](http://www.ponoko.com/), who do custom laser-cutting on a variety of materials. You can do the assembly and finishing yourself.

Comment: I was about to recommend this myself as it seems up the OP's alley

Comment: Wow it looks amazing ;) Thank you for the link. The best thing is they have a choice to build things in Italy so I could get them faster.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [Pedal Parts Plus](http://pedalpartsplus.com/) has a variety of pre-drilled cases and will do custom drilling for you. This looks like your best bet, if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

Some enclosures on Digikey have notices that the company will do custom drilling and cutouts on their stock enclosures (in sufficient quantities).  This is one such enclosure: notice the 'Customize your Enclosure' link: http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=SCR4B-ND

Here's a link to a presentation on the custom capabilities of Bud Industries:  http://dkc1.digikey.com/us/en/tod/BUD/ModifiedEnclosures_NoAudio/ModifiedEnclosures_NoAudio.html

So if you can find an enclosure on Digikey that gets close, some of the suppliers may be able to help you.

Comment: You don't need to go through Digikey to get this; talk to the manufacturers.  We've previously done similar mods through [Hammond Mfg](http://www.hammondmfg.com/) (qty ~1000).  However, they couldn't do all of the mods we needed, so we had to send them down to our mechanical/prototype shop.  Once the CAM machinery and jigs were set up, it took a couple days to run through them all.

Comment: +1 on Hammond - if you call them up, they can turnkey the CNC's end plates for you.  The other possibility is to just call a machine shop and have them fabricate replacement end plates from scratch (often cheaper than using the originally supplied end plates).

Answer (score 2):

Like the others said, manufacturers will often mod small quantities. However, for stuff like guitar stompboxes, some builders go the other way and make the hand-modification of the cases a reason to charge extra.

I don't have my links anymore, but I have seen a lot of boxes that were just off the shelf aluminum cases then hand painted, stained, corroded, or just polished with high quality hardware then sold for upwards of $300 each with about fifty cents in electronics inside. Some of these are truly works of art!

Another poster pointed out that the electronics is usually trivial, the real work is in the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a local guy with laser cutter - this way you can quickly make cases out of wood or metal(harder to do, obviously). Personally, I love wooden cases, no production items can have them :-)

Ordering 100 non-standard plastic cases on a factory is not possible, production preparation will eat your money for such a small series.

Comment: Lasering holes in thick metal would take longer than just drilling them, no?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to switch between different drills :-) Anyway, it's robot working, not you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Polycase, PacTec, Hammond, Bud for off-the-shelf enclosures that you can get custom cutouts done either turnkey from the manufacturer, or shopped out to a machine shop.

Also, check out ToolLess  - [www.toolless.com](http://toolless.com) - they claim to have a tool-less no-mold capability for unique shapes.  I haven't personally used them, but heard about them from a friend-of-a-friend, and it sounded pretty impressive.  The idea is that they 
"build up" the case by fusing/joining together sub-panels made up of cut sheets or hogged-out stock.